# I'm getting "Content type not set" error from my Integration test on Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, integration-testing

Im using integration tests in my small application. . Its simple CRUD. Everything is ok, except Save and Update mappings. tests give me "Content type not set
java.lang.AssertionError: Content type not set" error

This is controller class

```
package com.ilkin.simpletodo.controller;

import com.ilkin.simpletodo.exception.generic.EntityNotFoundException;
import com.ilkin.simpletodo.models.TodoItem;
import com.ilkin.simpletodo.services.TodoItemService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

import static com.ilkin.simpletodo.constant.Constant.TODO_ITEM_URL;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(TODO_ITEM_URL)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TodoController {

    private final TodoItemService itemService;

    @GetMapping()
    public List<TodoItem> findAll() {
        return itemService.getAllItems();
    }

    @GetMapping("{itemId}")
    public TodoItem findByItemId(
            @PathVariable("itemId") long id
    ) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        return itemService.getItemById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public TodoItem saveItem(
            @RequestBody TodoItem todoItem
    ) {
        return itemService.saveItem(todoItem);
    }

    @PutMapping("{itemId}")
    public TodoItem updateItem(
            @PathVariable long itemId,
            @RequestBody TodoItem todoItem
    ) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        return itemService.updateItem(itemId, todoItem);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("{itemId}")
    public TodoItem deleteItem(
            @PathVariable("itemId") long id
    ) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        return itemService.deleteItemById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping("{itemId}")
    public TodoItem changeItemStatus(
            @PathVariable("itemId") long id
    ) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        return itemService.changeItemStatus(id);
    }
}
```

This is Integration Tests:

```
package com.ilkin.simpletodo.controller;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.ilkin.simpletodo.TestsConfiguration;
import com.ilkin.simpletodo.exception.generic.EntityNotFoundException;
import com.ilkin.simpletodo.models.TodoItem;
import com.ilkin.simpletodo.services.TodoItemService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.ilkin.simpletodo.constant.Constant.TODO_ITEM_URL;
import static com.ilkin.simpletodo.utils.Utils.getJsonString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;


public class TodoControllerTests extends TestsConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    TodoItemService itemService;

    private TodoItem requestObject;
    private String requestBody;

    private TodoItem responseObject;
    private String responseBody;

    private List<TodoItem> responseObjectList;
    private String responseBodyList;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() throws JsonProcessingException {

//        mockMvc = standaloneSetup(new TodoController(itemService)).build();

        requestObject = new TodoItem();
        requestObject.setDone(false);
        requestObject.setTaskName("task");
        requestObject.setCreatedTime(LocalDateTime.now());
        requestObject.setUpdateTime(LocalDateTime.now());

        requestBody = getJsonString(requestObject);

        responseObject = new TodoItem();
        responseObject.setItemId(requestObject.getItemId());
        responseObject.setUpdateTime(requestObject.getUpdateTime());
        responseObject.setCreatedTime(requestObject.getCreatedTime());
        responseObject.setTaskName(requestObject.getTaskName());
        responseObject.setDone(requestObject.isDone());
        responseObject.setItemId(1);

        responseBody = getJsonString(responseObject);

        responseObjectList = new ArrayList<>();
        responseObjectList.add(responseObject);

        responseBodyList = getJsonString(responseObjectList);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("GET " + TODO_ITEM_URL)
    public void find_all() throws Exception {

        when(itemService.getAllItems()).thenReturn(responseObjectList);

        mockMvc.perform(
                get(TODO_ITEM_URL)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().json(responseBodyList));

        verify(itemService).getAllItems();
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("GET " + TODO_ITEM_URL + "/itemId")
    public void find_by_item_id_when_exist() throws Exception {

        when(itemService.getItemById(1)).thenReturn(responseObject);

        mockMvc.perform(
                get(TODO_ITEM_URL + "/1")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(content().json(responseBody));

        verify(itemService).getItemById(1);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("GET " + TODO_ITEM_URL + "/" + Long.MAX_VALUE)
    public void find_by_item_id_when_not_exist() throws Exception {

        when(itemService.getItemById(Long.MAX_VALUE)).thenThrow(EntityNotFoundException.class);

        mockMvc.perform(
                get(TODO_ITEM_URL + "/" + Long.MAX_VALUE)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        )
                .andExpect(status().isNotFound());

        verify(itemService).getItemById(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("POST " + TODO_ITEM_URL)
    public void save_item() throws Exception {

        when(itemService.saveItem(responseObject)).thenReturn(responseObject);

        mockMvc.perform(
                post(TODO_ITEM_URL)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(requestBody)
        )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(content().json(responseBody));

        verify(itemService).saveItem(responseObject);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("PUT " + TODO_ITEM_URL + "/itemId")
    public void update_item_when_id_exist() throws Exception {

        when(itemService.updateItem(1, requestObject)).thenReturn(responseObject);

        mockMvc.perform(
                put(TODO_ITEM_URL + "/1")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(requestBody)
        )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(content().json(responseBody));

        verify(itemService).updateItem(1, requestObject);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("PUT " + TODO_ITEM_URL + "/" + Long.MAX_VALUE)
    public void update_item_when_id_not_exist() throws Exception {

        when(itemService.updateItem(Long.MAX_VALUE, requestObject)).thenThrow(EntityNotFoundException.class);

        mockMvc.perform(
                put(TODO_ITEM_URL + "/" + Long.MAX_VALUE)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(requestBody)
        )
                .andExpect(status().isNotFound());

        verify(itemService).updateItem(Long.MAX_VALUE, requestObject);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("DELETE " + TODO_ITEM_URL + "/1")
    public void delete_item_when_id_exist() throws Exception {

        when(itemService.deleteItemById(1)).thenReturn(responseObject);

        mockMvc.perform(
                delete(TODO_ITEM_URL + "/1")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(requestBody)
        )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(content().json(responseBody));

        verify(itemService).deleteItemById(1);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("DELETE " + TODO_ITEM_URL + "/" + Long.MAX_VALUE)
    public void delete_item_when_id_not_exist() throws Exception {

        when(itemService.deleteItemById(Long.MAX_VALUE)).thenThrow(EntityNotFoundException.class);

        mockMvc.perform(
                delete(TODO_ITEM_URL + "/" + Long.MAX_VALUE)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(requestBody)
        )
                .andExpect(status().isNotFound());

        verify(itemService).deleteItemById(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("POST " + TODO_ITEM_URL + "/1")
    public void change_item_status_when_id_exist() throws Exception {

        when(itemService.changeItemStatus(1)).thenReturn(responseObject);

        mockMvc.perform(
                post(TODO_ITEM_URL + "/1")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(requestBody)
        )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(content().json(responseBody));

        verify(itemService).changeItemStatus(1);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("POST " + TODO_ITEM_URL + "/" + Long.MAX_VALUE)
    public void change_item_status_when_id_not_exist() throws Exception {

        when(itemService.changeItemStatus(Long.MAX_VALUE)).thenThrow(EntityNotFoundException.class);

        mockMvc.perform(
                post(TODO_ITEM_URL + "/" + Long.MAX_VALUE)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(requestBody)
        )
                .andExpect(status().isNotFound());

        verify(itemService).changeItemStatus(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }
}
```

When I start Integration testing Im getting 3 failed test(save_item(), update_item_when_id_exist() and update_item_when_id_not_exist()). I thought it was due to my repo item.save(). However nothing came out from debuging. I already tried solutions like adding - @PostMapping(produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE} )
didn't work for me.

Comment: Try consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE in your controller

Answer (score 1):

I guess the tests fail on the following check of content type:

```java
 .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
```

Try specifying the content type explicitly in `@RequestMapping` annotation:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/accounts", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Comment: as i mentioned in post, i already tried adding "produces" and "consumes" to my controller. Nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

So, I find my problem. It was about my request and response Object. I've forget set create and update variable for response, and integration test tried to check whether requestObject and responseObject equal or not. And test was throwing an error due to this issue